# Ranger Permissions | Hive table acess based on Partition Directory

Tags: hive, hdp, apache-ranger

I was looking for help on following usecase to be implemted by Ranger Authorization service in HDP.

I have a hive table **'customer'** which holds below two partitions loaded from HDFS.

**/data/mydatabase/customer/partition1/**

**/data/mydatabase/customer/SenstivePartition2/**

I have two user - user1 and user2 and I want to define a policy in such a way that

user1 --> should be able to access --> partition1

user2 --> should be able to access --> partition1 and SenstivePartition2 both.

As Second partition is highly sensitive therefore I do not want to define table level policy otherwise both user will get all access.

Thanks
Shashi

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set authorization based on partitions based on [this forum info](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/105029/how-to-set-user-authorization-at-parition-level-on.html). You can set up a partitioned materialized view in HDP 3.0.1 and later as [described in these docs](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.0.1/using-hiveql/content/hive_create_partitioned_materialized_view.html) and then set up the Ranger authorization on the views as tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly what you asked, but what may help you is the even more fine-grained row level access control.

Here is documented how you can set up row-level filtering in ranger for hive tables:
https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_security/content/ranger_row_level_filtering_in_hive.html